# How to execute python code after each stroke painted in image editor?

Tags: python, scripting, add-on, image, uv-image-editor

Is there any possibility for that? Modal operator seems to be not suitable for that

Answer (score 6):

You can achieve this by using a scene update handler that monitors the state of the active image in the image editor.

For this technique to work you need to:

1. Create or open an image in the image editor window on the active screen.
2. Save your image to an external file once.
3. Also: the script will save any change to file immediately. If you don't care about that, this solution can work for you.

The example below illustrates how you can set a new random paintbrush color after every stroke.

[image]

```
import bpy, random

def run_if_img_changed( scene ):
    im = None
    # References the active image in the image editor
    for a in bpy.context.screen.areas:
        if a.type == 'IMAGE_EDITOR':
            for s in a.spaces:
                if s.type == 'IMAGE_EDITOR':
                    im = s.image
                    break

    if im and im.is_dirty:
        ## Replace the bit in this if clause with your code
        print( "Image changed!" )

        # Set paintbrush to random color
        bpy.data.brushes['TexDraw'].color =  [ random.random() for c in 'rgb' ]

        ## End of replaceable sample code

        # Save image so it will no longer be dirty
        im.save() # This line will crash the script if you haven't saved the image to a file yet

bpy.app.handlers.scene_update_post.append( run_if_img_changed )
```

Comment: Getting image by name is cumbersome.
(im = bpy.data.images['Untitled.001'])
Is there a way to obtain currently editing image?

Comment: @wilddev, You can reference any image there, this is simply the example I used above. This is the name of your image, which you can set in the image editor.

Comment: handler function receives just a scene, but not a context of image editor. I don't know how to receive such a context inside a handler function =(

Comment: @wilddev, updated to read image from image editor. Lemme know if works as expected.